# How to use output of prompt as global variable in another function

Tags: javascript

Following Odin Project [Rock Paper Scissors](https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/foundations/courses/foundations/lessons/rock-paper-scissors) - trying to use a JS prompt input in another function to work out who won a game.

Have stripped a lot out to hopefully make the question/answer as reusable as possible for others.

I have 2 global variables set :

```
let computerSelection;
let playerSelection;
```

I have a function `(playRound)` which works out the outcome of a round (who won) which I know works when hard coding the `player selection` (as I've tried console logging the output successfully).

However I want to replace the hard coding of the player selection to use the input of a prompt. But when I do this, it isn't setting the `playerSelection` properly as I'm just getting '`undefined`' when I console log `playRound()`.

My prompt :

```
function showModal() {
    selection = window.prompt('Rock, paper or scissors?').toLowerCase(); 
    playerSelection=selection
}
```

I know this works when I console log the `playerSelection` with a different button like this:

```
function print() {
    console.log(playerSelection);
}
```

however, when I try use it in my `playRound()` function it is showing `undefined`?

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  computerSelection = computerPlay();
  playerSelection = showModal(playerSelection);
```

I've also tried just using

```
playerSelection = playerSelection
```

and also

```
playerSelection = showModal()
```

as I thought surely the global variable is set once the modal is complete but that is also returning undefined???

I don't understand why this isn't working in the `playRound` function as it seems the modal/prompt is setting the `playerSelection` variable (when I console.log `playerSelection` after doing it (using my test `print()` function?)

Comment: Note that in the real world developers rarely ever use window.prompt and use form controls instead

Comment: Yes thanks - I just didn't want to skip over this bit of the tutorial until I understood it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with scope here. Because you have a parameter called playerSelection being passed into the function it is setting that variable and not your global variable. You can solve this like this:

```
let playerSelection;
let computerSelection;

function playRound() {
  computerSelection = computerPlay();
  playerSelection = showModal(playerSelection);
}

function showModal() {
    return window.prompt('Rock, paper or scissors?').toLowerCase(); 
}

playRound();
```

Note that also you need to return the prompt result from showModal, a function without a return statement will always return undefined.

Comment: thanks! so close! but now I understand thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

working on this myself I did
let playerSelection = prompt(text)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).